# Can I store character type in python array?

Tags: python, arrays

```
from array import *
>>> ch = array('c',['A','B','D'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ch = array('c',['A','B','D'])
ValueError: bad typecode (must be b, B, u, h, H, i, I, l, L, q, Q, f or d)
```

When I compiled above python code, the compiler showed an error.

Comment: How about you use one of the documented type codes instead of "c": https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: because i also wants ask same question instead of "s". sorry

Answer (score 1):

The only supported `array` [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) for strings is Unicode character, with the type code `u`:

```
ch = array('u', ['A', 'B', 'D'])
```

Comment: thank you so much brother.Please suggest me any good book for python(basic?+advance)

Comment: Why not read the official documentation for [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)? All type codes are explained there.

Comment: i love reading books. sometime internet connection very slow or network issue.Please suggest me book in which all topics are precise and clear with examples

Comment: @Manjeet Look no further than https://www.python.org/doc/, which links to books, and even lets you download the documentation for offline reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to store ASCII characters, you can use unsigned char: `"B"`.
They must be converted with `ord()`, though:

```
ary = array("B", [ord(c) for c in ("A", "B", "C")])
# array('B', [65, 66, 67])

for i in ary:
    print(chr(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

use a list :

```py
# define list
chs = ['A','B','D']

# iterate on list
for ch in chs:

    # do stuff
    print(ch)
```

Answer (score -1):

try to initialize the array with `ch = ['A','B','D']` instead of calling `array()`

Comment: you mean to say that  i should use list instead of array?

Comment: yes, mainly because you do not need to specify the datatype of lists since python does that for you. you can still use array() but you would need to use a valid type code for that.

Comment: And what if using a typed array is precisely what OP wants to do…?!

Comment: ok then tell me valid type code for character type array ?